# How to Turn off Windows 7 Internet Time Sync Using C#?

Tags: windows-7

[image: Windows 7 Internet Time]

Hello all,

How would I go about turning off automatic internet time synchronization using C#?

I know I can turn it off by going to (Adjust Date & Time -> Internet Time) but I need to do it through C#. Maybe a registry key change?

Thanks much! Luke

Comment: Okay, so I found that Net Time: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490716.aspx
Would allow me to sync the time to a server, but how would I de-sync from the internet time programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
try
{
   Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters",
   "Type", "NoSync", RegistryValueKind.String);
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Could not change internet time sync. Registry error!!!");
}
```

Comment: It does not disables Windows Time service, probably will continue syncing.

Comment: You need to Stop Windows Time service too, see my post.